# HeaderComponent.html:313 ERROR TypeError: _co.logout is not a function

Tags: angular

header.component.html

```html
  <a (click)="logout()" class="dropdown-item" ><i class="ft-power mr-2"></i><span>Logout</span></a>
```

auth.component.ts

```js
    logout() {
        this.authService.logout();
        this.router.navigate(['Login']);
      }
```

auth.service.ts

```js
     export class AuthService {
        
          private apiRoot = 'http://localhost:8000/auth/';
        
          constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
        
        
          private setSession(authResuilt){
            const token = authResuilt.token;
            const payload = <JWTPayload>jwtDecode(token)
            const expiresAt = moment.unix(payload.exp);
        
            localStorage.setItem('token',authResuilt.token)
            localStorage.setItem('expires_at',JSON.stringify(expiresAt.valueOf()))
          }
          get token(): string{
            return localStorage.getItem('token')
          }
        
          login(username: string,password:string){
            return this.http.post(
              this.apiRoot.concat('login/'),
              {username,password}
            ).pipe(
              tap(response=> this.setSession(response)),
              shareReplay()
            );
          }
          logout() {
            localStorage.removeItem('token');
            localStorage.removeItem('expires_at');
          }
```

HeaderComponent.html:313 ERROR TypeError: _co.Logout is not a function

can any help why this error is coming

Comment: your function is with small l while in html its called with capital L. correct on either.

Comment: still facing the same error

Comment: For better solution we need to your `authService` code too

Comment: Can you share with us your controller?

Comment: now you can check

Comment: Error is on HeaderComponent.html, can you share that?

Comment: already shared.

Comment: From info so far there is good possibility that this might be an angular file watch issue or build issue. Have you tried rerunning ng serve or ng build --watch? And make sure files are saved

Comment: still facing the same error :/

Comment: Can you set it up on stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

This is a typo (first character is uppercased) : the function is named 'Logout' inside your template but 'logout' inside your component.

Answer (score 0):

Write same spelling of function `Logout()` in `html` and in `ts` file..

```
<a (click)="Logout()" class="dropdown-item" ><i class="ft-power mr-2"></i> 
  <span>Logout</span>
</a>

Logout() {
    this.authService.logout();
    this.router.navigate(['Login']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First use same function name in view and component either logout() or Logout
2. If still error check logout function in auth service